# JavaScript Date Formatting?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have a date string like so:

> '2016-06-16 00:00:00'

and would like to convert to this format:

> '2016-06-16T19:30:00.000Z'

Is there a standard approach for doing this? Angular may also be used!

Comment: Did you mind to google "angular date"? The first result [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) is angulars documentation

Comment: you haven't even try researching some related problem yet

Comment: yes as @baao suggested `<span>{{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}</span>` should fit with this.

Comment: Why did your input time of `00:00:00` become `19:30:00.000Z`? Are you assuming the input always comes from one specific timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default javascript function to get date like this:

```
new Date().toISOString();
```

Comment: Thank you. A simple answer for a simple question. Will accept when it lets me.

Comment: @user2085143 A simple question you could've found the answer for yourself in three seconds.